# Using session in login task in php language

Tags: php

Using SESSION to login with one tab and open other tab, copy URL in first tab and paste it to second tab - for example (crud operation) in two tabs and update the result after refreshing. At this logged in moment, what if anyone using other pcs to access my website by other browsers with same URL?

This is my code:

```
login.php
    <?php    
        require_once "navigation.php";
        require_once "connection_to_database.php";    
        session_start();
        // use mysqli to connect and fetch data from database    
        $method = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "REQUEST_METHOD");
        $action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "action");
        $field = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "field");    
        $page = "";
        if ($method == "POST") {
            if ($action == "login") {
                // check field is empty, same with pattern or not
                // escape value
                // compare with database value, set $_SESSION["username"]
                // navigate to user index page with this $_SESSION["username"]
                // display $_SESSION["username"]
                $page = "/user_index.php";
            }
        }
        forwardToPage($page);
    ?>
user_index.php
    <?php
        require_once "navigation.php";
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE || session_id() == "") {
            session_start();
            if (!(isset($_SESSION["username"]))) {
                forwardToPage("/login.php");
            }
        }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            ...
        </head>
        <body>
            ...
            <span>
                welcome <form action="/logout.php" method="post"><input type="submit" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>" /></form>
            </span>
            ...
        </body>
    </html>
```

I will appreciate if anyone can share knowledge or sample codes with me.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you share some code that you have made?

Comment: Yes, but this comment is too short. Can you show me how to do this because I am a new contributor?

Comment: I've figured out how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time you login to the website, the session ID will be send back and save to your browser cookies. And If someone open the same url, they don't have your session ID so they cannot behave as you in that website.

Comment: Is cookies saved to browser automatically or manually - backend (php) or frontend (javascript)?

Comment: I recommend you to check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171965/when-a-cookie-is-sent-via-http-header-to-a-browser-will-it-be-added-to-the-clien#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=It'll%20be%20handled%20automatically,send%20it%20on%20next%20requests.&text=Cookies%20are%20set%20using%20the,sent%20in%20an%20HTTP%20response.)

Comment: So I should code with javascript to check any cookie being set every time I visit a website if it existed, expired or "fiddler" tool to see it in clear. Thank you for this link.